# Getting the current date and or time in Elixir

Tags: elixir

This seems like a really dumb question but how does one get and display the current date or time in Elixir? I tried going through [the docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/) but couldn't find anything. Do I need to use an Erlang function?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

To answer your question more specifically (though I really appreciate Onorio's recommendation to use Timex!), you can get the current date and time from the Erlang standard lib using `:calendar.universal_time()` or `:calendar.local_time()`. There are a number of useful functions for working with Erlang's `datetime` type in the `calendar` module, but they are somewhat limited, and don't provide you with anything for parsing or formatting dates, which is where Timex comes in.

Comment: Great answer, thank you both and I will definitely check out Timex!

Comment: We now have: `DateTime.utc_now()`. And `Calendar.strftime/2` for formatting it.

Answer (score 76):

You can use [**`DateTime.utc_now/0`**](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/DateTime.html#utc_now/1) to get UTC DateTime.

Answer (score 43):

From Erlang 19.1:

```
:os.system_time(:millisecond)
```

From Erlang 18:

```
:os.system_time(:milli_seconds)
```

Gives the current UNIX timestamp UTC.

Thanks @HenrikN for linking the blog post http://michal.muskala.eu/2015/07/30/unix-timestamps-in-elixir.html

Comment: Link is dead—[Archive.org version here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190119170406/http://michal.muskala.eu/2015/07/30/unix-timestamps-in-elixir.html).

Answer (score 23):

### NaiveDateTime

If you don't care about the timezone and just want pure Date and Time, use [`NaiveDateTime`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/NaiveDateTime.html#utc_now/0):

```elixir
NaiveDateTime.utc_now
# => ~N[2017-11-30 20:49:54.660724]
```

---

### DateTime

If you want Timezone details as well, use [`DateTime`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/DateTime.html#utc_now/0), which will also return things like timezone name, UTC offset, STD offset, and timezone abbreviation:

```elixir
DateTime.utc_now
# => %DateTime{calendar: Calendar.ISO, day: 30, hour: 20, microsecond: {667345, 6}, minute: 51, month: 11, second: 58, std_offset: 0, time_zone: "Etc/UTC", utc_offset: 0, year: 2017, zone_abbr: "UTC"}
```

---

*You can then also call `to_date/1` and `to_time/1` from these modules to get the specific date and time values from the datetime structs.*

Answer (score 16):

It depends what format you want it in.

You can use any function in the Erlang standard library from Elixir. Traditionally, you would get the time with the [`now/0`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#now-0) function:

```
iex(1)> :erlang.now
{1487, 549978, 29683}
```

That represents `time_t` 1,487,549,978.29683, which is 19 minutes, 38.29683 seconds after midnight UTC on Monday, Feb 20, 2017.

However, since Erlang/OTP 18, that function is deprecated; one of the reasons is that Erlang guarantees that the return value will increase every call. If calling it in a tight loop on a machine fast enough to call it more than once per microsecond, the returned timestamp will get ahead of real time.

The replacement is [an API with more precision and control](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/time_correction.html). The primary interface to this new API is the [`os:system_time/0`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/os.html#system_time-0) function, which returns epoch time in a system-defined unit:

```
iex(2)> :os.system_time
1487549978296838000
```

You can request a specific unit with `system_time/1`, though:

```
iex(3)> :os.system_time(:millisecond)
1487549978296
```

Since Elixir 1.2, those functions have also been available in the native [`System` module](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/System.html#content):

```
iex(4)> System.system_time(:second)
1487549978
```

For a more friendly but still Elixir-native interface, use the [`calendar`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/calendar.html) module, which will give you tuples:

```
iex(5)> :calendar.universal_time
{{2017, 2, 20}, {0, 19, 38}}
```

Since 1.3, Elixir has also had its own suite of modules for manipulating dates and times: [`Date`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Date.html#content) and [`DateTime`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/DateTime.html#content). You can use its functions to get the current date or time like so:

```
iex(6)> Date.utc_today
~D[2017-02-20]
iex(7)> DateTime.utc_now
#DateTime<2017-02-20 00:19:38.29683Z>
```

Answer (score 12):

To get the number of milliseconds (Unix Timestamp):

```
DateTime.utc_now() |> DateTime.to_unix(:millisecond)
```

Comment: Nice one Sam, just what I was looking for ;)

Comment: Which (as above) would be converting `from_unix!/3` only to convert immediately back `to_unix/1`. DateTime docs have even a sentence about this: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/DateTime.html#to_unix/2

Answer (score 11):

I think your best bet is to use Paul Schoenfelder's (aka BitWalker) timex library for Elixir.  The lib is here: https://github.com/bitwalker/timex and you can get the package from hex.pm https://hex.pm/packages/timex.  Paul kindly provided a good explanation of how to use the library on the readme page of that github repo.

You could make calls to the native Erlang libs but I think Paul's lib is superior when one is dealing with Elixir.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation Onorio! For anybody reading this, I'm very open to contributions so that we can make Timex the go to library for date/times in Elixir, and perhaps one day merging it into the Elixir standard library if it should be up to par. If you are interested in helping, shoot me a message or dive in to the issue tracker on GitHub and send some pull requests!

Comment: @bitwalker Yeah, Erlang/Elixir has many things to do for the date/time lib. And I hope timex can be merged into Elixir, too :)

Answer (score 9):

You can also use `:os.timestamp\0`, which returns `{megaseconds, seconds, microseconds}` from UTC. `:os.timestamp |> :calendar.now_to_datetime` will give you now in erlang standard `{{YYYY, MM, DD}, {HH, MM, SS}}` format.

Comment: And to get that into a POSIX/UNIX timestamp: http://michal.muskala.eu/2015/07/30/unix-timestamps-in-elixir.html

Answer (score 6):

If you need to deal with Daylight Saving Time or time zones I made a library for that: [Calendar](https://github.com/lau/calendar).

To get the current time you would use for instance `Calendar.DateTime.now("America/Los_Angeles")` for the current time in Los Angeles or `Calendar.DateTime.now_utc` for the current time in UTC.

Answer (score 3):

Well, Timex to the rescue usually, however some of tricks below might be of help:

```
{erl_date, erl_time} = :calendar.local_time()
# {{2020, 11, 19}, {0, 6, 36}}

{:ok, time} = Time.from_erl(erl_time)
# {:ok, ~T[00:06:36]}

{:ok, date} = Date.from_erl(erl_date)
# {:ok, ~D[2020-11-19]}

Calendar.strftime(time, "%c", preferred_datetime: "%H:%M:%S")
# "00:06:36"


Calendar.strftime(date, "%c", preferred_datetime: "%m-%d-%Y")
# "11-19-2020"
```

Answer (score 2):

To get unix timestamp

```
DateTime.to_unix(DateTime.utc_now)
```

Comment: Which is converting `from_unix!/3` only to convert immediately back `to_unix/1`. DateTime docs have even a sentence about this:https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/DateTime.html#to_unix/2